# JSON data variable deciphering

Tags: java, android, json, spring, android-studio

Im slowly looking at json responses in Android Studio and i have been working through this example

http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/

I have it working, but what i am trying to decipher is where the elements are set. For example this currently can display the 'id' and 'content' section of a json response. What if i wanted to display 'date' from the response?

This is the mainactivity code

```
package org.hello.rest9;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    //.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            new HttpRequestTask().execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Greeting> {
        @Override
        protected Greeting doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting";
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                Greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting.class);
                return greeting;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Greeting greeting) {
            TextView greetingIdText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_value);
            TextView greetingContentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_value);
            greetingIdText.setText(greeting.getId());
            greetingContentText.setText(greeting.getContent());
        }

    }


}
```

and this is Greeting.class

```
package org.hello.rest9;

    public class Greeting {

        private String id;
        private String content;

        public String getId() {
            return this.time;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return this.content;
        }

    }
```

What i can decipher is that greeting.class sets the elements we want to grab, in this case content and id. but i would love to know how i could define other elements, for example replacing "content" with "date"

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an extra attribute `public String date;` to your `Greeting` class. Of course, you have to make sure that the data source JSON also has a field with the same name otherwise the template will not work...

If you replaced `content` with `date`, you still have to make sure that `"date"` exists in the data source JSON.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes the data source also has date. So basically i would add the extra attribute date and that would grab it? I have done this for example and then changed this TextView greetingContentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_value); to this TextView greetingContentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time2_value); and its giving me an error and not working (basically thinks it cant find time 2) i called string time2.